# JQuery is:focus not working in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer-8

I check for focus on a text field with this:

```
if ($('#title').is(":focus"))

<input type="text" id="title" value="Write your post..." />
```

every other browser determines this as true, IE8 does not. Does this work in IE8?

Comment: Out of curiosity, does it make any difference whether IE8's in quirks-mode, standards-mode (with a `<!DOCTYPE...>`) or compatibility mode?

Comment: Well, right now I'm testing in IE9 using IE8 standards...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work no matter what mode IE is running in:

```
if(document.getElementById('title')==document.activeElement)
```